# How to add Authors' family name and short title in header?

Tags: header-footer

I want to have authors' name be shown in the title as the following photo. Here, authors' names are shown in each line with their affiliation and email address.
[image]

Also, I want to define a short title. For example, if the full title is *"A Survey of Deep Reinforcement Learning in Recommender Systems: A Systematic Review and Future Directions"*, I want to define a short title like *"A Servey of DRL in RS"*. In the header, authors' family name, and the short title should be shown. For example, in this style, in even pages, the header is like this:

[image]

And, in odd pages, we have:

[image]

I search and found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68308/how-to-add-running-title-and-author) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622125/how-to-add-running-title-and-author-with-it-alternating), but it is different.

'''

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}   % For use of abs   >>> \abs{a}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{amsthm}    % To add a box at the end of the proof    \qed
\usepackage{setspace}  % To add space between lines \setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.9in, right=0.9in, top=1in, bottom=1in, footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.1in, right=0.2in, top=1in, bottom=1in, margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{tr}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red,
    linktoc=all,
    citecolor=red
           }
\usepackage{apptools}
\AtAppendix{\counterwithin{lemma}{section}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% For writing algorithms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%%% Coloring the comment as blue
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}                % Set the Input
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}              % set the Output



\setstretch{1.35}

 %\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

%% Setup of theorem styles. Outcomment only one.
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     % Preferred (Theorem 1, Lemma 1, Theorem 2)
%\TheoremsNumberedByChapter  % (Theorem 1.1, Lema 1.1, Theorem 1.2)
\ECRepeatTheorems
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,% make the links colored
}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{54, 58, 202}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{A Survey of Deep Reinforcement Learning in Recommender Systems: A Systematic Review and Future Directions}
\author{Xiaocong Chen, Lina Yao, Julian McAuley, Guanglin Zhou, Xianzhi Wang}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=myblue}\tableofcontents}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please give us a sample document that shows the document class you are using. You say that the linked questions are different, but you don't say how. So add to your sample document the `fancyhdr` code you've tried and we can help you sort out the details.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: You should submit a **working** document. `\TheoremsNumberedThrough` and `\ECRepeatTheorems` are not LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, but I hope it helps others to help you out. With thee the following code, you can format the authors under the title.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=0.9in, right=0.9in, top=1in, bottom=1in, footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for generating dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}


% Set the title, authors, and short title
\title{A Survey of Deep Reinforcement Learning in Recommender Systems: A Systematic Review and Future Directions}
\author{
  Xiaocong Chen\\
  Institution\\
  Address\\
  \texttt{email}
  \and
  Lina Yao\\
  Institution\\
  Address\\
  \texttt{email}
  \and
  Julian McAuley\\
  Institution\\
  Address\\
  \texttt{email}
  \and
  Guanglin Zhou\\
  Institution\\
  Address\\
  \texttt{email}
  \and
  Xianzhi Wang\\
  Institution\\
  Address\\
  \texttt{email}
}
\newcommand{\shortauthor}{Chen et al.}
\newcommand{\shorttitle}{A Survey of DRL in RS}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty} % suppress page number in first page

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1} % start page numbering from 1
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-30] % dummy text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the address or institution is larger, then each author will be in a single line.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by scd:

In order to get different headers on left and right pages you need the `twoside` option, either

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
```

or

```
\usepackage[twoside]{fancyhdr}
```

The extra commands you need are:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[OL,ER]{\shortauthor: \shorttitle}
```

[image]

[image]